# Android Studio - Gradle always builds all modules instead of just the one I run

Tags: android, android-studio, build, gradle, android-library

I´m developing an android library in Android Studio.

To test it, I´ve added a second module which is a Test Application for the library.

When I´m building the library to release a new version, it always runs the Test Application too. If I have errors just in my Test Application, I can´t even build the library at all!

**Why doesn´t it just build the one I´ve triggered?**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem. So far I don't know why this happens. Fortunately there seems to be a workaround:

In the "Run configurations" node of your "Gradle projects" tab right click the task which doesn't work for you. Then choose "Edit right configuration" option. Modify the "Tasks:" text field in a way that you put module name before the task name. E.g. let your task be "build", then edit

```
Tasks: | build
```

text field to

```
Tasks: | :your.module.name:build
```

Don't forget the semicolons.